# what is the spring cloud stream kafka binder version that includes maxRequestSize

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am running into the below exception when publishing an event to the kafka topic

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 2063239 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

I looked at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/587

I am using the below spring cloud versions and did not provide any version to `spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder` in my pom

```
<spring-cloud-stream.version>Brooklyn.SR3</spring-cloud-stream.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Brixton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
```

**what spring-cloud-stream version jar should I use in order to use this property?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Brooklyn (binder 1.1.2), use the general `configuration` property map...

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.request.size=
```

for a global setting or

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<dest>.producer.configuration.max.request.size=
```

for a specific destination (e.g. `output`).

Comment: No problem. It is customary, here, to mark an answer 'accepted' if it solves your problem (click the check/tick mark under the voting buttons on the left). It will help others looking for answers in future.

Comment: I am having issues with the kafka client -0.8 thats inherited from spring-integration which is inside the spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka dependency. Here is my pom.xml  [link](https://github.com/sw-enthusiast/spring-cloud-stream-kafka/issues/1) Do you know which release of spring-cloud-stream supports the kafka 0.9

Comment: The [Spring Cloud Stream documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_the_binder_with_apache_kafka_0_10) explains how to override kafka versions.

Comment: Spring Integration 2.0.x uses Kafka 0.9, 2.1.x uses 0.10.

Comment: I am downloading the pom itself like this 
           `<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>`

and 
 `<spring-cloud-stream.version>Brooklyn.SR3</spring-cloud-stream.version>`

which gives me spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka version 1.0.2

Comment: Gary - is there any way to achieve this using the Chelsea binder release? Importing the Brooklyn release version leads to all sorts of transient jar conflicts with Spring Boot 1.5.4 in my project which your advice above did not resolve.

Comment: The setting will work with Chelsea too; you should not downgrade to Brooklyn for this. Double check your configuration. Post a new question showing your configuration if you're still having problems.